# ajax response not picked in django form

Tags: ajax, django

I am new to django,python and ajax.I have a django form with 4 fields. Out of the 4 fields, one field's data is based on selection of previous field. I have used ajax to achieve this.My ajax response is fine. It is being populated in my html page.But,when i submit the form, that field is empty in view.
Here is my forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.Form):   
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['FunctionType'] = forms.ChoiceField(label='FunctionType',choices=function_choices(), widget=Select(attrs={'onChange':'get_function_type()'}),required=False)
        self.fields['SubFunctionType'] = forms.ChoiceField(label='SubFunctionType',choices=subfunction_choices(),widget=Select,required=False)
        self.fields['FromDate'] = forms.CharField(label='FromDate',max_length=30,required=False)
        self.fields['ToDate'] = forms.CharField(label='ToDate',max_length=30,required=False)
```

where function_choices() and subfunction_choices() are functions that fetches the choices from database. The subfunction type should be changed on selection of a particular function type.
Here is my javascript function which is called "onchange".

```
function get_function_type() {
    var functionVal = document.getElementById("id_FunctionType").value;
    if (functionVal == "---- Select a Function Type ----")
    { 
    alert ("Please select a valid function");
    }
    else
    {
    new Ajax.Request('/test/select_subfunction', { 
    method: 'get',
    parameters: $H({'FunctionType': FunctionVal}),
    onSuccess : function(transport) { 
     var e = $('id_SubFunctionType')
      if(transport.responseText)
            e.update(transport.responseText)
    }
    }); // end new Ajax.Request
   }
}
```

The view corresponding to /test/select_subfunction is,

```
def select_subfunction(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'GET':
        func_type = request.GET.get('FunctionType','')
        SubFunctionType = { (values fetched from database) }
    return render_to_response('Input.html', {'SubFunctionType':SubFunctionType},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

A single HTML template is used, as below,

```
  <form id="UserForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action=""> {% csrf_token %} 
  <table align="center">

  <tr>
      <td > Function Type * {{ form.FunctionType }} </td> </tr>
   <td > SubFunction Type * {{ form.SubFunctionType }} </td> </tr> 

     {% for c in SubFunctionType %}   
       <option value="{{ c.SubFunctionType }}">{{ c }}</option> 
     {% endfor %}      
      <td > From (YYYY-MM-DD) <br> {{ form.FromDate }} </td> </tr>
      <td > To (YYYY-MM-DD) <br> {{ form.ToDate }} </td> </tr>
  </form>
</table>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

The Subfunction values are populated based on Function selection but it is blank in view.
The request.POST output is as below,

```
POST:<QueryDict: {u'FunctionType': [u'Laptop'], u'ToDate': [u''], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'Z8JjC04imL3Tkn0XYPFL2EZ5znzvssar'], u'SubFunctionType': [u''], u'FromDate': [u'']}>,
```

For the function type laptop, it displays all makes of laptop. I selected HP. So, the subfunction should contain HP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved. Just changed,

```
{% for c in SubFunctionType %}   
       <option value="{{ c.SubFunctionType }}">{{ c }}</option> 
{% endfor %}
```

to

```
{% for c in SubFunctionType %}   
       <option value="{{ c }}">{{ c }}</option> 
{% endfor %}
```

Just removing ".SubFunctionType " helped.